# Resume from hibernation (pm-hibernate) randomly reboots

Tags: boot, hibernate, resume, pm-utils

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome as primary window manager (not Ubuntu Gnome, just installed Gnome after Ubuntu). I often tend to use pm-hibernate to get into hibernation, but when I boot again the resume sometimes, but not always, fails and the computer reboots. At the second boot, the GRUB bootloader screen won't countdown the timer anymore and it will wait for my input. I'd really like to analyze why this is happening, but I don't even know in which log file to look for "resume errors" or where to start. Can you give me a hint on this?

About a year ago it all worked very well, but suddenly (I don't know when exactly) that all started and I don't know what I have changed to make this happen.

Kind regards,

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have problems with the "standard" Ubuntu hibernate, have a look at [TuxOnIce](http://tuxonice.nigelcunningham.com.au/) especially their [Ubuntu PPA](https://launchpad.net/~tuxonice/+archive/ppa) as these guys follow up their errors much faster then Canonical itself.

I haven't had a single problem since starting to use them (and my laptop *didn't* work at all with Ubuntu hibernation...)

That being said: you should [never install a PPA because someone tells you to](https://thepcspy.com/read/linux-isnt-invulnerable/) (including me).  You should always use personal judgement whether to install a PPA or not. That being said, a highly regarded PPA with thousands of users should be held in higher regard then `PPA:Maffia.it/Vincenzo`.

Comment: As you're a reputation 3 user: If this all works, don't forget to click the grey check-mark under the "0" at the left of this text, which means "yes, this answer is valid"!  ;-)

Comment: Thanks, this may be a correct answer, but here in my case it just lead to destruction of the whole UI. When resuming with tuxonice it gets stuck and won't continue after the progress bar in the boot screen is full. Rebooting then leads to a blank screen, where only the terminals are working, but not the UI. Even restarting gdm did not help. I needed to reboot and use another kernel to get my UI back. So I'll wait a bit with clicking on the "answered" button, sorry.

Comment: Wow!  Never had that happen to me with anyone I have given TuxOnIce... You should file a bug with Nigel as he's pretty good at follow-up. (just not right now as BugZilla seems to be down)

Comment: I'll mark it as answered now, as I couldn't find any other solution. Maybe something is totally wrong with my system, so I will reinstall it in a few weeks when I got time to do so.

Comment: Please keep me posted on the hibernation and if you're going to re-install anyway, read [What is the best backup strategy for 1 PC](http://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) as well as it contains a few gems on how to install your OS...